# Generating a coveringGrid clipped by the input geometry

Tags: google-earth-engine, intersection, vector-grid

I'm trying to generate a rectangular vector grid from a `FeatureCollection` using `ee.Geometry.Polygon.coveringGrid`, and clip it to the borders of the original vector.

However, the `intersection` function is not working as expected; it correctly clips the grid, but dissolves all the grid cells, resulting in a single polygon identical to the original `FeatureCollection`. I have also tried mapping it over each individual feature in the grid, with the same result.

The following code produces the desired output, but it feels a bit hacky, nongeneral and inefficient. Is there a way to achieve the same thing using `ee.Geometry.Polygon.intersection`?

```
// Load the country features from the LSIB dataset.
var countries = ee.FeatureCollection('USDOS/LSIB_SIMPLE/2017');

// Specify the country of interest.
var country = 'Bolivia';
var selected = countries.filter(ee.Filter.eq('country_na', country));
var buffer = ee.Feature(selected.first()).buffer(200000); // Large enough to cover cells outside border
var bufferClipped = buffer.geometry().difference(selected);

// Construct grid and intersect with country polygon
var grid = selected.geometry().coveringGrid(selected.geometry().projection());
var gridCountry = grid.geometry().difference(bufferClipped, 1);

// Display the grid on the map.
Map.addLayer(gridCountry, {}, 'Grid clipped');

// Center the map on selected country.
Map.centerObject(gridCountry);
```

Desired output:

[image: Desired output]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can map over your grid feature collection and return the intersection of each feature with the country polygon. This outputs a new feature collection:

```js
// Load the country features from the LSIB dataset.
var countries = ee.FeatureCollection('USDOS/LSIB_SIMPLE/2017');

// Specify the country of interest.
var country = 'Bolivia';
var selected = countries.filter(ee.Filter.eq('country_na', country));

// Construct grid and intersect with country polygon
var grid = selected.geometry().coveringGrid(selected.geometry().projection());

// selected is a feature collection, with one feature, so retrieve the first feature
// selected.first() is a computed object and must be cast to an ee.Feature
var bolivia = ee.Feature(selected.first())

// map over the grid feature collection and intersect with bolivia polygon
var gridClipped = grid.map( function(feat) {
                      return bolivia.intersection(feat, 0.1) // 0.1 is the allowed error margin
                  })

// debugging
print(gridClipped);

// add to map
Map.addLayer(gridClipped)
```